# Cell showing Date but not Time

Tags: excel, datetime, date-formatting

In my Excel sheet I added the date and time in one cell as below.

[image: SO18396706 example]

At the top (in fx bar) it is showing both the date and time. The problem is, in the cell it is showing only the date but I want both the time and date to be displayed in the cell.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select ColumnB, Home> Cells - Format, Format Cells and under Category: select Custom and in Type: enter `dd-mmm-yy hh:mm AM/PM`.

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + ;` will show the date, press the space bar, then `ctrl + shift + ;` will show the time, also.

```
09/08/2017     2:36 PM
[ctrl+;]       [ctrl+shift+;]
```